# Is a 2 weeks trip to the UK with a campervan feasable?

Tags: uk, road-trips, england, scotland, yorkshire

My boyfriend and I are planning to go to the uk in a month from july 16th until july 30th. I live in brussels so we would take the van to calais and they take the ferry to dover. So far we wanted to visit those places :

1. White Cliffs (optional)
2. Brigthon
3. Stonehenge
4. Bath
5. Bristol
6. Longleat Heage Maze
7. Coventry
8. Liverpool
9. Loch ness
10. Edimburg
11. Fingal's cave
12. Crinan Canal
13. Lake district national park
14. Yorkshire national park
15. Eilean Donan Castle (optional)
16. Isle of sky
17. Cape wrath (optional)

There are several issues with this planning. The first one is that we would go with my boyfriend's campervan and the wheel is on the left side of the van while driving on the left side of the road. I don't know if that is feasible. Also with the van inside cities, it seems a bit complicated. And we would have to go to camping spots. I am not familiar with camping in the UK, but I don't know how much ahead we would need to book and i'm a little bit concerned money wise to how much does a spot costs.

The second issue is that, I think we have scheduled too much for 14 days. I don't know how much time do places require or if there are some places that are actually not very interesting and would like to know which path to favor.

Answer (score 2):

> **the wheel is on the left**

Not a problem.

Stay alert when starting a journey on small roads with few or no other cars around you. It is easy to accidentally start driving on the wrong side if there are no other cars in sight.

You'll have more trouble overtaking but you are unlikely to do much overtaking in a campervan and the passenger can help keep a lookout.

> **I don't know how much ahead we would need to book**

It depends on when you are travelling - if it coincides with summer school-holidays I would book ahead.

If it is off-season, less popular areas, and/or you don't mind the risk of driving for hours looking for somewhere to stay - or finding a B&B, then you can take more risks.

> **I think we have scheduled too much for 14 days**

I agree, It looks like you'll spend most of your time on the motorway. Some of those places can be explored in a couple of hours, others can be enjoyed for months or years without visiting the same spot twice (e.g. [Wainwrights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Wainwrights))

I'd pick one or two main centres. Aim to include places near or between those centres. Don't spend too much time driving - you'll get bored and tired.

Tired drivers have more accidents and less fun.

This is largely a matter of personality though. Some people like to have detailed, well-researched plans made well in advance, others like to be completely spontaneous and don't mind the occasional disappointment or memorable hardship.